# Move scrollable contents relatively with jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, scrollto, scrolltop

I have a container with scrollable contents, and I need to move the position of the scroll *relatively* to its current position, say 20 pixels downwards. I'd like to use [ScrollTo](http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/ScrollTo) plugin, alternatively the `scrollTop()` jQuery function.

So if I run the desired command again and again, the container scroll is supposed to continue moving until reaching the end. Pseudo-code:

> $(myContainer).scrollTo(  { delta: '+20px' } );

Comment: scrollTo seems capable, but its [documentation](http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/) could be better. Best documentation is in the full implementation file. I note that scrollTo does have a way of moving stuff relatively: `$(...).scrollTo( {top:'-=100px', left:'+=100'}, 800 )`. Sorry to say code like this results in no scroll movement in my code. Could be a bug in the plugin, could be something in my code :(.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

scrollTop should do it:

```
$('#myContainer').scrollTop($('#myContainer').scrollTop() + delta);
```

[try it on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XHKTz/)

Comment: Thanks, your suggestion works, and thanks for the link to jsfiddle (excellent!). Only problem I've got now is a [jScrollPane bug](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10445403/jscrollpane-scrollbar-disappears-when-applying-scrollto) that cancels the scroll movement if the scrollbar originated at the top.