# jScrollPane scrollbar disappears when applying scrollTo

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, scrollto, jquery-jscrollpane

I have a problem with the jQuery extension [jScrollPane](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com) combined with the [scrollTo](http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/ScrollTo) plugin. The scrollbar disappears if I apply the `scrollTo` command to the scrollable container **and the scroll is at the top position**. (If the scroll is not at the top position, everything is working fine.)

To get the scrollbar back, I try to reinitialize it. What happens then is that the scroll goes back to the top, canceling the `scrollTo` command.

My code:

```
  $('#myScrollableDiv div.jspContainer').scrollTo(delta);
  c = $('#myScrollableDiv').jScrollPane({
        autoReinitialise: true,
        maintainPosition: true
  });
```

Comment: If I delay the second statement, I can actually see the DIV scrolling to the correct position from the top position, but when `jScrollPane` is applied, it goes back to the top. As far as I can tell, it looks like a bug in jScrollPane.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use jScrollPane, you have to use the functions of jScrollPane to scroll down.

```
var delta = 20;
var element = $('#myContainer').jScrollPane();
var api = element.data('jsp');
$('#scroll').click(function() {
    api.scrollByY(delta);
});​
```

[Try it on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rUk34/1/)

Refer the [jScrollPane Api](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/api.html) for a list of functions for the api variable.

Note: It doesn't work when you omit the `p` tags around the text.

Comment: Thanks, you're a saviour! I obviously used the wrong command for scrolling the jScrollPane contents, and I also applied it to the wrong DOM element. Funny that I got it so far with a flawed approach.